# Xamarin iOS console output problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, console.writeline

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. I have installed the Xamarin Trial. I am using the following example code AppDelegate.cs in a Xamarin iOS Universal project.

When I use `Debug.WriteLine` to write a message to the Visual Studio output window I seemingly get my message repeated 3 times.

When I use `Console.WriteLine` my message is not repeated, however, there seems to be some kind of race condition occasionally causing some of my messages to break over two different lines.

**Example Code :**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace LandingDay.Example1.Xamarin.iOSUniversal
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }

        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("This is a test. ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is a test. ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Required Behavior :**

To be able to write to the Visual Studio Output window as in the example code in a Xamarin iOS Universal project without my messages getting repeated 3 times or getting intermittently broken over multiple line.

Comment: Have you tried Trace.WriteLine() ?

Comment: To be fair, I hadn't tried Trace - though I just did. I get the 3 times repeated behavior again as with Debug.

Comment: Are you able to post more of the code you are using the writeline in?

Comment: Done. This should be easy enough to reproduce unless there is a problem with my setup.